# Mule Expression component not able to fetch value from properties file

Tags: mule-component

I want to fetch values dynamically from properties so I have implemented one poc. In that poc I have declared one object with value in mule expression component. After that I am fetching the value key from properties file. It is showing exceptions while testing the application.

```
Exception MSG: Root Exception stack trace: unresolvable property or identifier: $
```

EX-1:

```
flowVars.deptCode=21432143;
property3=${flowVars.deptCode};
```

EX-2:

```
property3=${21432143};
```

In the above two examples ex-2 has worked fine and ex-1 has failed .

Please let me know if anyone have clarity on that.

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Mule is using Spring Properties which can be kept in a seperate properties file and then retrieved/used in your application via ${propertyName}.

A property placeholder is used to define where you keep those properties.

Ex 1 is not possible because properties are not aware at all of any variables or properties inside of your Mule application.

Another issue is that those files will be loaded when the application is started.
If you change the value of a property a restart of your application is needed, so your approach isn't going to work.

More info in the docs here:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-properties

Comment: you are welcome, please mark as answered if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataweave script to dynamically read values from property file

```
#[dw("p(flowVars.deptCode)")]
```